# ResourceExhaustedError When running network demo fourth try

Tags: tensorflow, memory, graph, overflow, out

I have 1600 videos and I want to make joint annotation label data about videos.

I've already made the open pose network and I put my videos as input of the network and saved the joint data as json file.

When I put my first video data as input, there are no errors. And when I put second, third video as input, there are no errors too.

But When I put the fourth video data as input, I got these error message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Rbd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FghF8.png)

these above images are the error message.(OOM)

The size of first, second, third, fourth video is the same.

When I change name first and fourth video name, I got the same error when putting fourth video.

I think this error is about the graph. but I couldn't know why exactly.

I think there are many genious on stackoverflow. So please answer my question... :)

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by using cpu. not using gpu.

I use cpu only in tensorflow for solving this problem. and it works!